# Get nested value of constant by name dynamically

Tags: c#

I have a class storing constant value like the following below

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public const string A = "AValue";
    public const string B = "BValue";
    public const string C = "CValue";
}

var name = "A";
Console.WriteLine(typeof(FirstClass).GetField(name).GetValue(null)); //AValue
```

working pretty good, here the question, once i change the structure to contain nested classes, i did this

```
public class SecondClass
{
    public class SecondClassOne
    {
        public const string A = "AValue 1";
        public const string B = "BValue 1";
        public const string C = "CValue 1";
    }

    public class SecondClassTwo
    {
        public const string A = "AValue 2";
        public const string B = "BValue 2";
        public const string C = "CValue 2";
    }
}

var className = "SecondClassTwo";
var name = "A";
foreach (Type type in typeof(SecondClass).GetNestedTypes()){
    if(type.Name.Equals(className)){
        Console.WriteLine(type.GetField(name).GetValue(null)); //AValue 2
    }
}
```

It still working fine, ***but instead of using for loop to get through all the nested classes, is there any better way to do this***? Because the list may get longer and longer, it seems not really great to loop all these listing 1 by 1.

Comment: You could create a Map of types and fields - `[TypeName, [FieldName, Field]]` (Something like `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, FieldInfo>> Map`)

Comment: @Fabjan i would love to build as an dictionary, unfortunally I have no control on the constant list classes, thanks for the advice btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just use [`Type.GetNestedType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getnestedtype?view=netframework-4.7#System_Type_GetNestedType_System_String_):

```
var nestedType = typeof(SecondClass).GetNestedType(className);
Console.WriteLine(nestedType.GetField(name).GetValue(null));
```

However, if you're using this a lot, I'd strongly consider building a dictionary instead - particularly if all your constants are strings. You'd potentially end up with a `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>>`:

```
public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>> GetConstants() =>
    typeof(SecondClass).GetNestedTypes()
        .ToDictionary(
            type => type.Name,
            (IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>) 
            type.GetFields().ToDictionary(f => f.Name, (string) f => f.GetValue(null)));
```

(That's not currently constructing a `ReadOnlyDictionary`, but you certainly could do that.)

Comment: I've added the link to official documentation of the relevant overload. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Fabjan: Good call, will do.

Comment: thanks for the answer, have no idea `.GetNestedType()` able to pass class name into it.. unfortunally i would like to use dictionary but i have no control of the constant list, thanks for the advice as well.

Comment: @Dean: I'm not sure what you mean by "no control of the constant list" - I'm suggesting building it up with reflection based on the existing classes. It's a different way of accessing it at execution time, that's all.